# C++ InMemory Cache Library

Tags: c++, memcached

we have an application which utilizes a UDP service , and observe that 75% of calls to this UDP service is repeated.

Hence would wish to apply an In-Memory Cache , so as to avoid the costly network call and improve the application's turn-around time.

Never used caching before , hence any pointers on suitable cache libraries in C++/Unix environ would greatly help.

Also would like to share this cache across multiple processes.

The cache is required to store key value pairs of string type.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [redis](http://redis.io/), it's a noSQL key-value database. Here you have an [interactive tutorial](http://try.redis-db.com/). We use it in several of our applications successfully.

Answer (score 1):

[Gemfire](http://www.vmware.com/products/application-platform/vfabric-gemfire/overview.html) (no relation) is a commercial distributed caching system. Servers are written in Java but native support exists for C++ (among others).